# Programatically set default dial app in Android

Tags: android

I am trying to programatically set a new default dialing app using my device owner app.
Below is the code that i am using:

```
mDeviceAdmin = new ComponentName(this, AdminReceiver.class);
mDpm = (DevicePolicyManager) getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE);
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
filter.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
filter.addDataScheme("tel");
ComponentName activity = new ComponentName("com.dialer_app", "com.dialer_app.MainActivity");
                            mDpm.addPersistentPreferredActivity(mDeviceAdmin, filter, activity);
```

Below is the manifest file of the app that i am trying to set as default

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.dialer_app">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.BentoDialer">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.DIAL" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.DIAL" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:scheme="tel" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

The new dialer app is installed on the device but the code above does nothing.

Have any suggestions, please?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I have managed to find a solution that is working fine for me.

At first i set de current default dialer app as hidden. After that i am able to se the new app as default.

Below the code.

```
mDeviceAdmin = new ComponentName(this, AdminReceiver.class);
mDpm = (DevicePolicyManager) getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE);

mDpm.setApplicationHidden(mDeviceAdmin, "com.google.android.dialer", true);

IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
ComponentName activity = new ComponentName("com.dialer_app", "com.dialer_app.MainActivity");
mDpm.addPersistentPreferredActivity(mDeviceAdmin, filter, activity);
```